# Insert command?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to load/merge an existing table into another.
I have a table, build with Opencart (A PHP based opensource e commerce template).

I am trying to merging from table Sheet1 into table OC_Product.

Sheet1 goes like this:

```
`Sheet1` (`ccode`, `cname`, `cdescription`, `cprice`, `cimageurl`, `ccategory`)
```

OC_product table goes:

```
`oc_product` (model, price, image)
```

ccode equals model, cprice equals price, cimageurl equals image

There is some empty fields in OC product. However i need to generate a new numeric number for each of the imported products from Sheet1 aswell. As this is used for primary key in the Open Cart DB to operate between the other tables.

I guess the easy option would just be to duplicate the ccode into that aswell, as this is unique.

However i am in doubt how that is done with SQL query.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "import" the data from one table into another, you can do the following:

```
INSERT INTO oc_product (model, price, image)
SELECT ccode, cprice, cimageurl
FROM Sheet1
```

For the primary key, I would suggest to insert an identity numer for the new table

Comment: Thanks alot :).
Would there be anything wrong with just importing the ccode twice?
1 into model and 2 into "primary-key".
Like this
`INSERT INTO oc_product (product_id, model, price, image)
    SELECT ccode, ccode, cprice, cimageurl
    FROM Sheet1`

Edit: sorry for bad format.

Comment: That would be possible but it isn't a good solution imo since you would have the same information twice. if the model/ccode is unique anyway, then why don't you use it as primary key directly?

Comment: Yeah.
I just figured it would be less troubleful than having to correct the php code from using different primary key in all the MVC files ;)